# Is it possible to bind a domain to another domain instead of a server ip?

Tags: security

How to bypass/manipulate HTTP_HOST?

I want, in a browser, that when I go to `blabla.com`, it actually opens `example.com`(ip:`123.45.56.78`).

Using windows `.hosts` file, I can bind `blabla.com` to `123.45.56.78` server, and manipulate it.

This works with dedicated ip websites, but on shared servers there are several websites binded with IP (if `blabla.com` is not set on that ip already) then it shows "FORBIDDEN, domain doesn't exist on server".

Is there any way that visiting `blabla.com` opened `example.com`?

Comment: I think you should ask this question on server fault.

Comment: You'd need to run both websites on the same IP and add the alias `blabla.com` to the vHost config of `example.com`. Otherwise, no, not really. The DNS specifications doesn't allow that on root level.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it doesn't work is the hosts file does not affect the [HTTP host header](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.23) sent by the browser.

It is possible to do that though if you use e.g. [Burp Suite](https://portswigger.net/burp/) as an HTTP proxy.

`Proxy > Options > Match and Replace` allows the host header to be rewritten.

`Options > Hostname Resolution` allows the domain to be rebinded.